# Developing application using the .NET framework licensing

Tags: .net, licensing

Are there any license requirements when using the .NET framework for creating a commercial application?
Is there everything you need to know in the .NET framework EULA ? (i.e when you install .NET 4) or are there other requirements too ?
Talking about the EULA, it says that you have to have a licensed version of the OS.I do have an XP license but if I want my application to be used on Windows7, should I get a 7 license too?

As far as redistributing the framework,I am not planning to do so but will ask the user to download it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked to a lawyer, not the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Licenses tend to be rather complex legal documents, and I am not a lawyer (nor are most people on this site) so any answers you get her should be viewed only as opinion and not advice.

In general, the license is intended to be rather permissive.  You can't reverse engineer the code, change it, and call it your own.. you can't sue MS for providing it, etc. etc..

The term you refer to about the licensed OS means that your right to use the framework extends only to running it on a licensed version of the OS.  That means, legally you are not allowed to run the code on an unlicensed OS, which of course cannot be legally run either.  That doesn't mean you have to buy a license for Windows 7 if someone else is going to run it on Windows 7.  You only need a license for Windows 7 if YOU are going to run it on Windows 7.

Your end users are responsible for making sure they have a licensed OS, and they aren't allowed to run your program that uses the framework on an unlicensed OS.  But, practically speaking, if they're knowingly using it on an unlicensed OS they probably won't respect the framework license either.

I wouldn't worry too much about the terms of the license, unless you're doing something VERY wrong, then you're using it as Microsoft intended it to be used.